# IDataProtectionProvider Protect data in one project and and trying to Unprotect data in another project is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

In project 1 my updated code is

private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

```
public UsersV2Controller(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
           _protector = provider.CreateProtector("ManagementPortal.Controllers");
        }

In method 

_context.Users.Add(applicationUser);
_context.SaveChanges();
string token = _protector.Protect(applicationUser.Id);
var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { token = token, email = user.Email }, Request.Scheme);
```

Here if use Unprotect method it is working fine.

In my project2

private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtectionProvider;

public AccountController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider) {

_dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("ManagementPortal.Controllers");

}

And in method

var token = _dataProtectionProvider.Unprotect(token);  it is giving error like

[Unprotect method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9yRf.png)`

```
your text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two different applications need to share protected payloads, they should ensure that this property is set to the same value across both applications.

You can set the [ApplicationDiscriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionoptions.applicationdiscriminator?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property like this in your Startup or Program (asp.net core 6+). If you set it to the same value in both project, it will work.

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection(p =>
{
    p.ApplicationDiscriminator = "SetValueHere";
});
```

Comment: This does not work.